# OmniThreadLibrary C++ builder Build issues

Tags: delphi, c++builder, omnithreadlibrary

I'v been trying to get OmniThreadLibrary to run in builder, i've built it with all the c++ required files it builds ok but when i use it in an c++ builder app i get a bunch of error messages that look like the following

[bcc32 Error] DSiWin32.hpp(385): E2040 Declaration terminated incorrectly

one points at this line of code in the generated hpp file

static const System::Int8 CSIDL_ADMINTOOLS = System::Int8(0x30);

has anyone had this working in C++ builder or know the best way to resolve these issues

I'm using c++ builder settle and OmniThreadLibrary version 3.06

Comment: I've raised this as an issue see link for details https://github.com/gabr42/OmniThreadLibrary/issues/72

Comment: Why the vote down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Win32 API (and Delphi, for that matter) already declares  `CSIDL_ADMINTOOLS`, Omni should not be declaring it at all.  It should be using Delphi's `Shlobj` unit instead.

The Win32 API declares `CSIDL_ADMINTOOLS` using a `#define` statement:

```
#define CSIDL_ADMINTOOLS 0x0030
```

So the declaration in Omni's `.hpp` is getting modified by the C++ preprocessor to this:

```
static const System::Int8 0x0030 = System::Int8(0x30);
```

Thus the "Declaration terminated incorrectly" compiler error.

When Delphi code declares something that already exists in C++, it needs to be declared as either [`{$EXTERNALSYM}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/External_Symbols_(Delphi)) or [`{$NODECLARE}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/NODEFINE_directive_(Delphi)) to avoid duplicate declarations, and then optionally use [`{$HPPEMIT}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/HPP_emit_(Delphi)) to output a relevant `#include` statement in a generated `.hpp` file.  Delphi's units already do that for its Win32 declarations.

If Omni is not already doing that (and the error would suggest it is not) then it needs to be updated accordingly.

Comment: Hi Remy. Thanks I've managed to get it working by commenting them out for now. It looks like they did some but I guess not all.

Comment: @Shaun07776 you should file a bug report with the Omni author.

Comment: Yeah I will do. I don't think they every report to support c++ builder but it seems to be working ok. I ahead a few other issues after that I'll raise those to. Thanks for your help